# Access data tables from SQL Server in R

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to analyse data in R, from tables that are stored in a database within SQL Server. I have no problem making the connection between R and the SQL Server, but I am unable to continue on to access the tables. It seems like it should be simple but I just get this error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

load packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(RODBC)
library (DBI)
library(tidyverse)
```

Connect R to the SQL Server:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SQLserver", timeout = 10)
```

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from dbo.Vessels")
```

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1769: 42000:
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.Vessel'.
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>  'select * from dbo.Vessels'

Comment: Error seems clear that no such table exists. Are you sure `Vessels` table or view resides in default, `dbo` schema? Check all tables in database: `SELECT TABLE_SHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`.

Comment: Isn’t there a function that will tell dbo to cough up a list if valid table names?

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, of course, that's just standard SQL. However, the error message is strange because it shows `'dbo.Vessel'` (without `s`) and OP queried `dbo.Vessels` (with `s`).

Comment: Are you using quite an old ODBC driver there? Currently supported ODBC drivers would return either `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]` or `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]` at the start of their error messages but yours doesn't even include a version number.

Comment: i'm no R expert but you don't seem to pass a database name, so i'm guessing it defaults to master db, which probably doesn't contain your table. you can either pass db explicitely, or use: `select * from yourdb.dbo.vessels` perhaps